# Video capture in LWR

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, community, lwr, lws

We have developed some small LWC that start the device camera to take a picture.
It uses getUserMedia method in navigator.mediaDevices and works perfectly for internal users in Sales Cloud. When trying to run the component in Customer Portal the camera is not available.

We have disabled the Locker Service and enabled Relaxed CSP and LWS in the Portal but it did not affect the component.

Please help.